# Transfer Delay enabled. Only one purchase per block allowed

Tags: uniswapv2

I am using uniswap v2 router in with the following code:

```
  function mintNFT(address recipient)
    public payable 
    returns (uint256) {
      require(msg.value >= mintCost, "Insufficient funds");
      require(bytes(tokenURI).length > 0, "Token URI not set yet");
      require(locked != 1, "Contract Locked");
      require(minted + 1 <= MAX_SUPPLY, "Max Supply Hit");

      buyAndSend();
      uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
      _tokenIds.increment();
      _safeMint(recipient, newItemId);
      _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);
      minted += 1;
      return newItemId;
  }

  function buyAndSend() internal {
    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    uint amountOutMin = mintCost * percentage / 100;
    if (amountOutMin > 0) {
      address WETH_ADDRESS = uniswapRouter.WETH();
      path[0] = WETH_ADDRESS;
      path[1] = TOKEN_ADDRESS;
      address to = address(this);
      uint deadline = block.timestamp + 100;
      uniswapRouter.swapExactETHForTokens{ value: amountOutMin }(amountOutMin, path, to, deadline);
      IERC20 my_tokens = IERC20(TOKEN_ADDRESS);
      require(my_tokens.balanceOf(address(this)) >= 0, "Insufficient funds");
      my_tokens.transfer(REWARD_WALLET, my_tokens.balanceOf(address(this)));
    }
  }
```

I am getting this error when attempting to mint:
Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"execution reverted: _transfer:: Transfer Delay enabled. Only one purchase per block allowed.","id":4001018723196707}

This function works correctly on goerli but is failing on mainnet.